# Visual Studio 2015: Search html tag not having attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio-2015, editor

I want to search html tags from all the html files which do not contain specific attribute.
For Example Suppose I have following two tag in my two separate html file

```
<select id="id1"></select>  //in file demo.html
<select ui-select2 id="id2"></select> //in file demo1.html
```

Now I want to search only the tag which does not contain attribute "ui-select2" from all the html files.
so it should show me the file demo.html which contain following tag from above example.

```
<select id="id1"></select>
```